# loop until the capital has doubled c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to create a loop that has a given initial capital and a fixed annual percentage rate (interest) that prints out the current capital for the current year up to and including the year in which the capital has doubled.

for example the initial capital is 3000 and the interest is 12.

```
//3000*(1 + 12 / 100) = 3360

output
year 1 = 3360
year 2 = 3763.2
year 3 = 4214.78
year 4 = 4720.55
year 5 = 5287,02
year 6 = 5921,46
//end (when the initial capital(3000) has doubled (6000))
```

what i need help with is to create a loop that will calculate and show the output until the capital has doubled with either a for loop or while loop. the output doesnt have to be like the example but something similar.

here is the code ive created so far:

```
double initialcapital = 0;
double interest = 0;
int year = 0;
double capital = 0;

Console.Write("Initial capital: ");
initialcapital = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Interest: ");
interest = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

capital = initialcapital * (1 + interest / 100);
year = year + 1
Console.Writeline(capital);
```

Comment: Look at the [Iteration Statements (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the exact number of years before the amount doubles you can use this:

```
double exactYears = Math.Log(2) / Math.Log((100 + interest) / 100);
```

Otherwise the following will work for you:

```
double initialCapital = 0;
double interest = 0;
int year = 0;
double capital = 0;

Console.Write("Initial capital: ");
initialCapital = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Interest: ");
interest = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
capital = initialCapital;

while (capital < initialCapital * 2)
{
    capital = capital * (1 + interest / 100);
    year = year + 1;

    Console.WriteLine("Years: " + year);
    Console.WriteLine("Capital: " + capital);
}

Console.WriteLine("Years: " + year);
Console.WriteLine("Capital: " + capital);

double exactYears = Math.Log(2) / Math.Log((100 + interest) / 100);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Capital doubled in exactly: {0:0.000} years", exactYears));
```

Comment: this is really useful for me but one last thing that i need is also to print out what the capital is for each year /thanks

Comment: I've added a couple of Console.WriteLine() for you, but I think you probably could have managed that :-)

Comment: but that code give me the exakt same outut as the ones below :p, want the output to be something like the example i wrote on top, but im going to pussle with it after im done eating

Comment: Just change the Console.WriteLine inside the while loop, it's trivial.

Comment: just figured it out, problem was that i need only to use the initial capital code calculation once, once i changed it it worked like i wanted, the only thing i need now is to add year 1+ each time it calculates until the conditions are met

Comment: If you look at the code above, "year = year + 1;" does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 void displayCapital(double initalcapital, double interest){
     int year = 1;
     double capital = initialcapital;

     while(initialcapital > capital / 2) {
         Console.Write("Initial capital: ");
         initialcapital = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

         Console.Write("Interest: ");
         interest = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

         capital = initialcapital * (1 + interest / 100);
         year = year + 1
         Console.Writeline(capital);
     }
}
```

just call displayCapital(3000, 12); and you are done

Comment: Also, might want to change double to Decimal for currency calculations!

Comment: @Antonio Papa
i can get that output without the while loop, what i need to do is to multiply capital with interest until the capital has reached the doubled of initial capital

Comment: yes this can do that while (initialcapital > capital / 2 does that)